# How to restore the original mnemonics from shares?

Tags: mnemonic-seed

I just read that an original mnemonic can be split into parts, I am a little confused about how the system can restore the original mnemonic from these mnemonic pieces.

example i have mnemonic

```
radar warm pizza grief worth attack van ribbon milk surface guitar bachelor
```

and then i split and get 5 shares mnemonic

```
1. demise reopen sort defy forward gorilla live cannon scan large thing action
2. arch peasant act box try install indicate organ tourist hungry biology thought
3. gun win grace exhaust movie sail cable news bundle glide bright minimum
4. load sunny bicycle dragon ghost sort turtle buzz orbit slender bargain photo
5. recipe snake submit gentle squirrel tattoo boy penalty sail summer tongue dove
```

The three 3 shares that I combined, turned out to be really the original mnemonic. but here I have a question. If I only remember 2 of the 5 mnemonic shares, can I recover my original mnemonic? if possible please show me how?

thank you

Answer (score -1):

You can select what subset of the shares are enough to reconstruct the original secret. That's why it's called m of n. So set m to 2 and n to 5 and you have what you need.

If you haven't done this before splitting the secret then 2 shares will not be enough.

Comment: can u show me please?

Comment: @ZmxAtah i have no idea what tool or script you used so how can I show you?

Comment: I just using shamir secret from [iancoleman](https://iancoleman.io/shamir39/). 
but I don't know much about the shamir secret

Comment: just select 2 of 5 parts when splitting the secret

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. OP is trying to reconstruct their secret with just 2 shares that were created as part of a 3-of-5 setup. This is impossible.